# Setup:upgrade error after upgrade to Magento 2.3.3

Tags: magento2.3.3, magento-upgrade, setup-upgrade

I just upgrade my Magento 2.2.5 to 2.3.3 , and After running `bin/magento setup:upgrade` i got the following error:

```
Warning: Illegal string offset 'max_items' in  vendor/magento/framework/App/Config/Scope/Converter.php on line 41
```

[image]

core_config_data
[image]

Comment: i guess you have upgraded magento, but you forgot to upgrade your custom modules and theme package. please confirm.

Comment: @MagenX yes i already replace the Weltpixel module with the one that support 2.3, still got the same error

Answer (score 0):

You should delete all the config which are related to the module Weltpixel in the db table **core_config_data**